# How to convert DATE to UNIX TIMESTAMP in shell script on MacOS

Tags: linux, macos, date, shell

On Linux you can convert a date like "2010-10-02" to a unix timestamp in shell script by

```
date -d "2010-10-02" "+%s"
```

Since Mac OS does not have the equivalent **-d** for **date**. How do you go about converting a date to a unix timestamp in a shell script.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`man date` on OSX has this example

```
date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "`date`" "+%s"
```

Which I think does what you want.

You can use this for a specific date

```
date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "Tue Sep 28 19:35:15 EDT 2010" "+%s"
```

Or use whatever format you want.

Comment: ON OSX Terminal using bash shell I am unable to use the above command 
Ex: currDate=`date +%Y%m%d`
date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "${currDate}" "+%s"

Comment: @Jagdeep This'd work on OSX only if the Timezone specified is that of system's timezone. I am in `PDT` so  in the above command, changing `EDT` wtih `PDT` worked for me.

Answer (score 142):

```
date +%s
```

This works fine for me on OS X Lion.

Comment: Works in Linux as well (Ubuntu 10.04)

Comment: OP asks about converting a specific given date to a timestamp. `date +%s` will just use the current date.

Answer (score 18):

`date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" "2010-10-02" "+%s"`

Answer (score 4):

I used the following on Mac OSX.

```
currDate=`date +%Y%m%d`
epochDate=$(date -j -f "%Y%m%d" "${currDate}" "+%s")
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can install GNU date like so:

1. install Homebrew: https://brew.sh/
2. `brew install coreutils`
3. add to your bash_profile: `alias date="/usr/local/bin/gdate"`
4. `date +%s`
   1547838127

Comments saying Mac has to be "different" simply reveal the commenter is ignorant of the history of UNIX. macOS is based on BSD UNIX, which is way older than Linux. Linux essentially was a copy of other UNIX systems, and Linux decided to be "different" by adopting GNU tools instead of BSD tools. GNU tools are more user friendly, but they're not usually found on any *BSD system (just the way it is).

Really, if you spend most of your time in Linux, but have a Mac desktop, you *probably* want to make the Mac work like Linux.  There's no sense in trying to remember two different sets of options, or scripting for the mac's BSD version of Bash, unless you are writing a utility that you want to run on both BSD and GNU/Linux  shells.

Answer (score 3):

`date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "2020-04-07 00:00:00" "+%s"`

It will print the dynamic seconds when without `%H:%M:%S` and `00:00:00`.

Comment: Nice, thanks. If you `man strftime`, you'll see that "%F is equivalent to %Y-%m-%d" and "%T is equivalent to %H:%M:%S". So I think you can shorten your `input_fmt` to "%F %T" if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a date in UTC to a Unix timestamp:

```
date -ju -f "%F %T" "2021-03-08 14:56:21" "+%s"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a set of scripts that provides a uniform interface for both BSD and GNU version of `date`.

Follow command will output the Epoch seconds for the date `2010-10-02`, and it works with both BSD and GNU version of `date`.

```
$ xsh /date/convert "2010-10-02" "+%s"
1286020263
```

It's an equivalent of the command with GNU version of `date`:

```
date -d "2010-10-02" "+%s"
```

and also the command with BSD version of `date`:

```
date -j -f "%F" 2010-10-02 "+%s"
```

The scripts can be found at:

- https://github.com/xsh-lib/core/tree/master/functions/date

It's a part of a library called `xsh-lib/core`. To use them you need both repos `xsh` and `xsh-lib/core`, I list them below:

- https://github.com/alexzhangs/xsh
- https://github.com/xsh-lib/core