# How to convert human readable date into YYYYMMDD in linux/unix and get the weekday?

Tags: linux, date, unix, unix-timestamp

I would like to convert the human readable date into YYYYMMDD. Just wondering how can I do this. Thanks.

Input Date :-

```
Sep 30, 2016 11:20:34 AM
```

Output Date :-

```
20160930112034 
5 (Friday)
```

Comment: Do you want to do this with bash? In that case this question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508819/convert-date-formats-in-bash

Comment: by unix/linux, do you mean `bash`?

Comment: Yes its in bash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert DATE to UNIX TIMESTAMP in shell script on MacOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817750/how-to-convert-date-to-unix-timestamp-in-shell-script-on-macos)

Comment: When I searched for `[osx] convert date' there are numerous OSX specific answers close enough to help you solve this problem. Please try searching before posting. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This command will have exact output you have posted at Ubuntu 16.04:

```
$ date -d"Sep 30, 2016 11:20:34 AM" "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S %n%u (%A)"
20160930112034 
5 (Friday)
```

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122471/date-command-on-mac-os) you might need to adjust it for Mac os.
Check this command for ex.:

```
$ date -j -vJulm -v20d -v1999y '+%A'
```

Here is [manual](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html) for date command for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Bash solution:

```
$ date -d"Sep 30, 2016 11:20:34 AM" "+%Y%m%d - %A"
20160930 - Friday
```

Comment: I am using mac osx terminal and these commands do not work some how.

Comment: That is _very_ likely `/bin/date` and not a bash builtin.

Comment: There is no /bin/date dir on my mac osx terminal.